# Unable to run the pvcreate command

Tags: hard-disk, vmware

I am running Linux Ubuntu via VMWare. Currently it has been allocated a space of just 20 GB. I increased the same by 1 GB, on a trial basis. The new partition is named sda3 (screen shot of sudo parted -l is attached) which shows that a space of 21 GB is available. However, when I run the pvcreate command, it fails with the error message:

**pvcreate /dev/sda3** 
**Device /dev/sda3 not found (or ignored by filtering).**

I am running the pvcreate command, so that the disk analyser tool is able to detect this area in order for Linux to use it. 
Note: I am following the steps listed here: http://www.ireasoning.com/articles/linux_vmware_resize_disk.php (in case required).

[image: PartedCommand]

What might be the reason pvcreate fails? Also, should the new partition be created as a LVM or just a simple linux partition if I intended to use it just for storage purposes?

Thanks!

Comment: Try running with the `--debug` flag.

Comment: @FaheemMitha, you mean pvcreate -- debug /dev/sda3?

Comment: Yes, `pvcreate --debug /dev/sda3`.

Comment: @roaima, I am just experimenting since this is my first time.  Will use a larger space (~150GB) once I am sure about what I need to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partition 3 is only 1MB long, which isn't enough to create a PV.

**Empirical evidence**

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M count=1 > dd.img
loop=$(losetup  --show --find dd.img); echo "$loop"
# /dev/loop0
pvcreate "$loop"
# Device /dev/loop0 not found (or ignored by filtering).
losetup -d "$loop"
rm -f dd.img

dd if=/dev/zero bs=10M count=1 > dd.img
loop=$(losetup  --show --find dd.img); echo "$loop"
# /dev/loop0
pvcreate "$loop"
# Writing physical volume data to disk "/dev/loop0"
# Physical volume "/dev/loop0" successfully created
losetup -d "$loop"
rm -f dd.img
```

**Discovery**

Further investigation shows that at least 2MB (2048000 bytes) is required for `pvcreate` to succeed. It turns out that this is defined in the `lvm.conf`(5) file with the keyword `pv_min_size`, where the [man page](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/cgi-bin/manpage?5+lvm.conf) states

> **pv_min_size** -- Minimal size (in KB) of the block device which can
>                be used as a PV.  In clustered environment all nodes have to use
>                the same value.  Any value smaller than 512KB is ignored.  Up to
>                and include version 2.02.84 the default was 512KB.  From 2.02.85
>                onwards it was changed to 2MB to avoid floppy drives by default.

So there you have it. I've learned something today, too.

Comment: I am just experimenting since this is my first time. Will use a larger space (~150GB) once I am sure about what I need to do.  Also, my aim is to increase the total available application space, that's all!

Comment: @abhishek_naik If the answer is useful, upvote it. if it solves your problem, accept it.

Comment: @roaima if what  you say is correct, the error message is extremely misleading and imo should be reported as a bug.

Comment: @FaheemMitha it's documented, and it turns out that "ignored by filtering" is actually the correct message for the context. (Misleading? Yes. A bug? Probably not.)

Comment: I believe you. :-) It looks like the error message is issued because it matches something in the filter in `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf`. But at a minimum it could point the user to that config file...

Comment: @roaima, so I got the issue - I am using just 1 MB. However, could you please help me understand how just 1 MB? I mean, which is the command that I must have used to allocate 1 MB? In the VM settings, I had allocated 1 GB. While running the fdisk commands, I remember I had just entered one number 3 (to create sda3) and rest all were characters like n (create a new partition), w (write the new partition table), etc? I am not sure where just this 1 MB came from.

Comment: @abhisheknaik the 1MB is the gap between your primary partition 1 and your extended partition 2. It appears you may have 1GB space at the end of your disk (after the extended partition)

Comment: @roaima, this is very helpful.  Thank you! :)